# profile_update hook doesn't works inside a class

Tags: plugins, hooks, oop

When I try to use profile_update hook inside a class the callback function is not called.

```
public function __construct() {
  add_action('profile_update', array( $this, 'user_profile_update', 10, 2) );
}
function user_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
  die(var_dump($old_user_data));
}
```

Outside the class the callback function works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Careful where you are placing your brackets.

The hook should look like;

`add_action('profile_update', array( $this, 'user_profile_update' ), 10, 2 );`

Note the close bracket after the method name

Answer (score 0):

It's working:

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'profile_update', array( &$this, 'user_profile_update' ), 10, 2 );
}

public function user_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
    die( var_dump( $old_user_data ) );
}
```

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: `priority` and `accepted_args` fixed.

Comment: Please, edit your answer. Otherwise it does not seems to be useful.

Comment: `10, 2` is not valid in question. check exactly.